# How do I call a function in a different class in the Kivy Language?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am new to Kivy and the KvLang and have a question about functions and the class system in the KvLang.

I am building GUI that shows the user three images and gets them to select their favourite, by clicking on a button beneath the image. The purpose of this is for me to practice building custom widgets (which in this case is just an image with a button underneath it). I would like it so that the button the user clicks turns green, and the other buttons turn red.

Here is what I have so far... I have indicated where I think the problems are with an arrow <---

My .kv file:

```
<ImageButton@BoxLayout>:
    image_source: ''
    image_text: ''
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Image:
        source: root.image_source
        size_hint_y: 0.9

    Button:
        id: button
        text: root.image_text
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        on_release: main.choose_one()        <--- ERROR

<CustomWindow>:
    id: main
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    spacing: 10
    padding: 10

    ImageButton:
        id: one

    ImageButton:
        id: two

    ImageButton:
        id: three
```

And my .py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import os


class CustomWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.image_sources = self.get_images('images')
        self.image_boxes = [self.ids.one, self.ids.two, self.ids.three]
        self.show_images(self.image_sources)

    def show_images(self, images):
        for widget, image in zip(self.image_boxes, images):
            widget.image_source = image
            widget.image_text = image[image.rfind('/') + 1:image.rfind('.')]

    def choose_one(self, instance):        <--- ERROR
        for widget in self.image_boxes:
            widget.button.background_color = (1, 0, 0, 1)
            instance.background_color = (0, 1, 0, 1)

    @staticmethod
    def get_images(path):
        all_files = os.listdir(path)
        images = []
        for file in all_files:
            images.append(os.curdir + '/' + path + '/' + file)
        return images


class CustomApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CustomWindow()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CustomApp().run()
```

When I run this code I get the error `NameError: name 'main' is not defined`. My understanding of the problem is that Kivy can't find widget with the id 'main' in the `<ImageButton>` class. How can I tell it to look in the `<CustomWidget>` class? Any further advice or feedback on my approach is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://inclem.net/2019/06/20/kivy/widget_interactions_between_python_and_kv/

Comment: Also you are confusing kv rules with class instances. You need to access the instance of the class you want, the kv code is just a rule for how each instance is created. Also, the id main won't help you here because ids are accessed via the root widget of a kv rule, but your id is _for_ the root widget - once you have a reference to that widget you won't need to use ids to make use of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change:

```
on_release: main.choose_one()
```

to:

```
on_release: app.root.choose_one(root)
```

This uses the keywords `app` and `root` as described [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#value-expressions-on-property-expressions-ids-and-reserved-keywords).

And modify the `choose_one()` method to:

```
def choose_one(self, instance):
    for widget in self.image_boxes:
        if widget != instance:
            widget.ids.button.background_color = (1, 0, 0, 1)
    instance.background_color = (0, 1, 0, 1)
```

This uses the `ids` dictionary as documented [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#ids).